# How can I handle smartphone and SLR photography in one library available in the cloud?

Tags: file-management, smartphone, photoshop-elements

I think I'm quite average when it comes to picture taking.  Both me and my wife use our smartphones to take pictures and film video snippets of ourselves and our son.  But I also use a SLR camera on occation, if I'm at a specific happening (a trip, a birthday etc.).

And I'm looking for a good solution for both storing, archiving and viewing images, without too much hazzle.  I've used Lightroom earlier.  And I feel I either store and organize the images, but then they are "stuck" on my computer.  Or I have them in the cloud making them easily available on my smartphone or by sharing them with my family.  But then it's difficult to organize the images.  It's also difficult to get the SLR images into the cloud in a simple way, if I want to do anything more than drop them in a pile in my cloud account.

In short, I want:

- to take images and video snippets using both smartphones and an SLR camera.
- to store all images/video snippets on one location, preferably in folders by date (like Lightroom) - both local storage (NAS, file server etc.) or cloud storage would be fine.
- to tag images/video snippets according to events and/or persons.
- to share the library or parts of the library with other persons.
- to view the library both on my Windows computer and on my smartphone (preferably listed by above-mentioned tagging).

I realize this is a little bit of an "I want it all" question.  But... can I? :-)  And would Photoshop Elements (perhaps in combination with some other smartphone apps) be able to handle this?

Comment: Please don't downvote without commenting.  What's wrong with my question?

Comment: The title just sounds like spam: "Will product XYZ solve all your problems?" - however, I'm not the downvoter. Why don't you synchronise the folder you import the files into with your NAS/cloud service? That way, you can do it all with Lightroom.

Comment: @flolilolilo Thank you for the feedback.  While I don't disagree with you, I'm not sure which title would sum up my use case in a simple but to the point question.  So perhaps the question is too vague for a StackExchange site?  If so I think it's a bit sad.  There are so many compentent people doing so much interesting stuff out there, and I'd love if it were OK to ask a *little* broad questions just to get a direction or to get simple inspiration.

Comment: @flolilolilo About synching the files to the cloud, how would I get metadata (tagging) from the library into the apps then?

Comment: I'm no expert with Lightroom, but I think it can save the metadata into the file itself (or at least into sidecar-files) - I'm absolutely confident that it could do so by exporting the files (which wouldn't be the best of options, I assume). If I may suggest so: Rephrase the question to something like "is there an easy workflow with Lightroom to get tagged images on various devices (such as smartphones)?" - mind you, I'm in a hurry ATM so I'm not sure if that wasn't asked before (do a search on it) or if that would be a "good" question (though it would be acceptable IMHO).

Comment: I "up-voted" this question as I believe it is a valid question that others may be interested in knowing the answer to.

Comment: The header asks one question, the body asks another. (Basically, the body asks, "Is PSE the answer for my specific list of requirements (some of which are not exactly what most people consider *average, everyday* requirements).

Comment: @MichaelClark I agree with you.  I've changed the title to something perhaps a little more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment due to under 50 rep so will make this.

To your question I believe google photos would be a good solution, the only issue is you're limited on how many "full" size images you can upload from SLR however if you allow google to compress you're giving effectively unlimited storage. It works as a cloud solution, can share it with anyone and can view it on both phone and desktop. It also allows for "minimal" editing (cropping, leveling, filters, brightness etc) but nothing like LR.

So to the bullet points you've listed;

"to take images and video snippets using both smartphones and an SLR camera."
You can add both photos and videos from both devices to the same location.

"to store all images/video snippets on one location, preferably in folders by date (like Lightroom) - both local storage (NAS, file server etc.) or cloud storage would be fine."
You can store all images/videos in one location, can also create folders/galleries for these, believe it keeps dates too. Acts as cloud storage.

"to tag images/video snippets according to events and/or persons."
You have the ability to share galleries with people via a shareable link or email or a large number of different options.

"to share the library or parts of the library with other persons."
same as the above question.

"to view the library both on my Windows computer and on my smartphone (preferably listed by above-mentioned tagging)."
This can be done by galleries but not by the 1 image however you could simply create 1 image galleries and do it this way or sort/create to suit as needs be.

Basically, I'd highly recommend google photos for this.

edit: https://gyazo.com/6da4c48235bf344f908520c532b1c5e7 - an example of google photos